# distributional derivative in L^2

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Assume I have a function $f \in L^2(R^d,\mu)$ or $f \in L^1(R^d,\mu)$.

**A.** 
Now I know that it as distributional derivative, right?

I call that $\partial f$.

**B.**
If I can show now that $\int (\partial f)^2 \mu < \infty $ is then clear that $\partial f \in L^2(R^d,\mu)$? And hence $f$ weakly differentiable and hence $f$ in the Sobolev space of twice differentiable functions?

**C.**
Or am I not allowed to write something like $\int (\partial f)^2 \mu$? When am I allowed to write this?

Comment: What do you mean by $(\partial f)^2$? In general, you can't multiply distributions. (Even if you make sense of that, it's also not clear how you integrate a distribution with respect to some measure.)

Answer (score 1):

Distributions act on (or "can be integrated against") smooth functions - thus the expression $\int (\partial f)^2$ doesn't make sense in general. To establish that $f$ is Sobolev, you need to first check that $\partial f$ is a *function* (technically that $\partial f = g \mu$ for some function $g$; but it's standard to conflate $\partial f$ with $g$ when the measure is fixed).

Once you have established this, you indeed just need to check that $\partial f$ is square-integrable, which is now a meaningful condition.

Comment: How can I establish that $\partial f = g \mu$? Do you have an example?
Assume for example that the measure $\mu$ is just the lebesgue measure... or that $\mu$ is some finite measure over $R$ if thats easier... Does then always exist such a function $g$?